# text around range input vertically shifted in html

Tags: html, input, range

I have the following code for range input along with some style applied:

```
<style media="screen">
    .contactinfo label{display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
  .contactinfo div ~ div {
  margin-top: 2px;
  }
  .contactinfo {background:lightyellow; border:10px solid yellow; margin-bottom:10px; width: 720px;}
  .contactinfo textarea {width: 180px; box-sizing: border-box;}
    </style>
    <fieldset class="contactinfo">
        <legend>Your indicators</legend> <br>
        <div class="">
          <label for="ht">Height:</label>
          Short <input type="range" name="ht" id="ht" value="" min="0" max="100"> Tall
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <label for="sal">Salary:</label>
            Poor <input type="range" name="ht" id="ht" value="" min="0" max="100"> Rich
        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

But the text on either side of range input are not aligned properly. Here is what it looks like now:
[image]
Even after I remove vertical-align:top it does not align properly. 
This is how it looks like now:
[image]
What I want is(ignoring the highlight):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `vertical-align:top;` 
see https://jsfiddle.net/aqfcde2d/